# How to select multiple columns in entity framework?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

In my first question I didn't explain well. But now I need to select some columns from a entity framework class.

```
var Muestra = Cecytec.asignatura.Select(Z => new asignatura { nombre = Z.nombre, horasPorSemana = Z.horasPorSemana, nivel = Z.nivel, unidades = Z.unidades }).ToList();
```

From my class(table) "asignatura" I have this:

```
public partial class asignatura
{
    public asignatura()
    {
        this.criterioevaluacion = new HashSet<criterioevaluacion>();
        this.evaluacion = new HashSet<evaluacion>();
        this.examen = new HashSet<examen>();
        this.alumno = new HashSet<alumno>();
        this.horario = new HashSet<horario>();
        this.profesor = new HashSet<profesor>();
    }

    public int idAsignatura { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> horasPorSemana { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> nivel { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> unidades { get; set; }
    public int semestres_idsemestres { get; set; }

    public virtual semestres semestres { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<criterioevaluacion> criterioevaluacion { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<evaluacion> evaluacion { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<examen> examen { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<alumno> alumno { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<horario> horario { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<profesor> profesor { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to show: 'nombre', 'horasPorSemana', 'nivel', 'unidades' and 'calificacion'

Note: 'calificacion' is in another class

```
public partial class evaluacion
{
    public int unidad { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> calificacion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> inasistencia { get; set; }
    public string observaciones { get; set; }
    public int asignatura_idAsignatura { get; set; }

    public virtual asignatura asignatura { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your projection you're projecting to an entity from your database. What you need to do is one of two options:

1. Project to an anonymous class

   var Muestra = Cecytec
   .asignatura
   .Select(Z => new
   {
   nombre = Z.nombre,
   horasPorSemana = Z.horasPorSemana,
   nivel = Z.nivel,
   unidades = Z.unidades,
   evaluacion_calificacion = Z.evaluacion.Select(e => e.calificacion)
   })
   .ToList();

This will give you a list of anonymous objects stored in the variable `Muestra` with each containing an `IEnumerable` of `calificacion` values from the evaluacion table.

2. Project to a predefined class with the properties you need

This is similar to the above but you just define a class to hold the properties.

```
public class ProjectionResult
{
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> horasPorSemana { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> nivel { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> unidades { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Nullable<double>> evaluacion_calificacion { get; set; }
}
```

Then run your projection like this:

```
var Muestra = Cecytec
    .asignatura
    .Select(Z => new ProjectionResult
        {
            nombre = Z.nombre,
            horasPorSemana = Z.horasPorSemana,
            nivel = Z.nivel,
            unidades = Z.unidades,
            evaluacion_calificacion = Z.evaluacion.Select(e => e.calificacion)
        })
    .ToList();
```

This will give you a list of `ProjectionResult` objects stored in the variable `Muestra` with each containing an `IEnumerable` of `calificacion` values from the evaluacion table.

Comment: OMG! the second works! Thank you Mr Member from Stackoverflow

Comment: @GertArnold correct, thank you. I've modified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is OK but it do not show

```
evaluacion_calificacion = Z.evaluacion.Select(e => e.calificacion)
```

Always null, to fix that I did this:

```
public class ProjectionResult { public Nullable<int> horasPorSemana { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> nivel { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> unidades { get; set; }
    //public virtual IEnumerable<Nullable<double>> evaluacion_calificacion { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> calificacion { get; set; } }
```

And to the query change the last line:

```
 var Muestra = Actualmente.Select(Z => new ProyeccionAcademica
                {
                    nombre = Z.nombre,
                    horasPorSemana = Z.horasPorSemana,
                    nivel = Z.nivel,
                    unidades = Z.unidades,                        
                    calificacion = Z.evaluacion.First(Find => Find.asignatura_idAsignatura == Z.idAsignatura).calificacion                        
                    }).ToList();
```

But thanks for your quick answer!!!